# python pygame check collide then make the item return to the origin site

Tags: python, pygame

Update 12/20

I set different value to the ship but the final site is not than expected

```
def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
    self.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
    aliens.update()
    collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
    if collide:
        aliens.empty()

        self.create(setting,aliens)

        ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
        ship.rect.y = ship.screen_rect.bottom

        ship.y =ship.rect.centery             # when collide, the ship disappear
        ship.x = ship.rect.centerx
```

#

```
def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
    self.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
    aliens.update()
    collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
    if collide:
        aliens.empty()

        self.create(setting,aliens)

        ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
        ship.rect.y = ship.screen_rect.bottom

        ship.y =ship.rect.y    #when collide, the x is not at the center and the y half of the ship under the screen
        ship.x = ship.rect.x
```

#

```
def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
    self.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
    aliens.update()
    collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
    if collide:
        aliens.empty()

        self.create(setting,aliens)

        ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
        ship.rect.y = ship.screen_rect.bottom

        ship.rect.centerx =ship.x   #notching change when collide, the ship not move
        ship.rect.centery = ship.y
```

=========================================================================

I am trying to implement a function that when the ship collide the aliens , return the ship to the bottom of the screen, restart the game.

So i use `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(sprite,group)` in my codes.

First i check both site , if return True then empty the `Group aliens` and put the ship to its origin site

But when i run the scripts, the effect is not what i want, when the ship collide the aliens, the ship return to the origin site and the whole screen stopped, nothing can move , the aliens the ship all stopped

I modify many times but nothing changed for the result, what cause this error?? the whole screen just stopped.

this is my code of this function:

```
def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
        self.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
        aliens.update()
        collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
        if collide:
            aliens.empty()

            self.create(setting,aliens)

            ship.rect.center=ship.screen_rect.center
            ship.rect.bottom=ship.screen_rect.bottom
```

here's the whole codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os
import pygame



class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1.5
        self.ship=3
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")
        self.bullet_s=3
        self.bullet_w=5
        self.bullet_h=20
        self.bullet_n=10
        self.bullet_c=(0,0,0)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)
        self.speed=1
        self.direction = 1

    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        spacex=setting.w-(self.rect.x)*2
        spacey=(setting.h)/2-self.rect.y
        alien_number=int(spacex/(2*(self.rect.width)))
        alien_row=int(spacey/(2*(self.rect.height)))
        for row in range(alien_row):
           for number in range(alien_number):
               alien=Alien()
               alien.x=alien.rect.x+2*alien.rect.width*number
               alien.rect.x=alien.x
               alien.rect.y=alien.rect.y+2*alien.rect.height*row
               aliens.add(alien)

    def ck_edge(self,setting,aliens):
       for alien in aliens.sprites():
           if alien.x > setting.w or alien.x < 0:
              alien.change_direction(aliens)
              break
    def change_direction(self,aliens):
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y +=50
            alien.direction *= -1

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.speed*self.direction)
        self.rect.x =self.x


    def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
        self.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
        aliens.update()
        collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
        if collide:
            aliens.empty()

            self.create(setting,aliens)

            ship.rect.center=ship.screen_rect.center
            ship.rect.bottom=ship.screen_rect.bottom

    def blit(setting,aliens):
        aliens.draw(setting.screen)

class Ship():
    def __init__(self,setting):
        bk=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/muha.png").convert()
        self.bkg=pygame.transform.smoothscale(bk,(setting.w,setting.h))
        temp=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/title.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.ship=pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp,(200,200))
        self.screen=setting.screen
        self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rect=self.ship.get_rect()



        self.rect.center=self.screen_rect.center
        self.rect.bottom=self.screen_rect.bottom

        self.x=float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)


    def blit_ship(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.ship,self.rect)
    def blit_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bkg,(0,0))



class Function():
     def __init__(self):
        self.moving_up   = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
     def event(self,setting,ship):      
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        sys.exit()

             elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right=False

     def move(self,setting,ship):

         if self.moving_up == True and ship.rect.top >= 0:
            ship.y -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_down == True and ship.rect.bottom <= setting.h:
             ship.y += setting.speed
         if self.moving_left == True and ship.rect.left >= 0:
             ship.x -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_right == True and ship.rect.right <= setting.w:
             ship.x += setting.speed
         ship.rect.centerx=ship.x
         ship.rect.centery=ship.y



def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    function=Function()
    ship=Ship(setting)
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien.create(setting,aliens)                  

    while True:
        ship.blit_screen()
        function.event(setting,ship)

        Alien.blit(setting,aliens)
        ship.blit_ship()
        function.move(setting,ship)
        alien.position(setting,ship,aliens)

        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```

Comment: No idea but what is blocking me from attempting to dig further is that your "whole code" is not quite a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I should be able to just paste your code into a shell and have it run, which I can't do as of now unless I mock in some images. You might have more success receiving answers if you replaced those with colored rectangles or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual location of the ship is not stored in the attribute `ship.rect`, it is stored in (`self.x`, `self.y`).
Of course, the ship is drawn at the location stored in `ship.rect`, but that location is updated from (`self.x`, `self.y`).

You've to reset (`self.x`, `self.y`), too:

```py
class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):
        # [...]        

        collide=pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens)
        if collide:
            # [...]

            ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
            ship.rect.bottom = ship.screen_rect.bottom

            # INSERT THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES
            ship.x = float(ship.rect.centerx)
            ship.y = float(ship.rect.centery)
```

Comment: I use ```ship.x = ship.screen_rect.centerx
            ship.y = ship.screen_rect.bottom-ship.ship.get_rect().height/2``` to set the correct site when the ship collide the aliens, but i not sure when i not ```-ship.ship.get_rect().height/2```, the half of the ship will out of the screen

Comment: I update the question,try 3 kinds of setting in ```def position(self,setting,ship,aliens):```, still not correct, the x,y coordinates always not on the bottom and center of the screen

Comment: it worked!! it may something wrong at privious script run,, now the ship site totally correct, many many thanks